# Update all outbound links passing UTM parameters to outbound links (and default value)

Tags: javascript, utm

I track my marketing campaigns using UTM parameters. All is good when I'm dealing with links within my website. However, I have a form hosted by Typeform and I need to forward the UTM to it so I can measure my campaigns performance there. I have almost zero JS knowledge but I found a JS below and was able to make it work, but just for the first link - I need to pass UTM on all links. Actually I think we could keep even internal links with UTM values, because people could navigate a bit on my website until they click on the outbound link to Typeform.

Ad CAMPAIGN > My WEBSITE > Typeform

For example:

```
https://test.com/?utm_source=sourcex&utm_medium=mediumx&utm_campaign=campaignx&utm_term=termx&utm_content=contentx`
```

Also, it would be great to have UTM empty when it's not detected as opposed to "null" I'm getting now.

Anyway, below's the script I've been using. How can I make it work for all links?

```js
// create urlParams variable (constant) from URLSearchParams class using current window
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// set UTM medium, source and campaign variables (constants) based on results of URSearchParams
const utm_medium = urlParams.get('utm_medium')
const utm_source = urlParams.get('utm_source')
const utm_campaign = urlParams.get('utm_campaign')
const utm_term = urlParams.get('utm_term')
const utm_content = urlParams.get('utm_content')

// get the Outbound button element
var outboundLink = document.getElementById("outbound");

// edit Outbound button element property by appending the URL parameters
outboundLink.href += "?utm_medium=" + utm_medium + "&utm_source=" + utm_source + "&utm_campaign=" + utm_campaign+ "&utm_term=" + utm_term + "&utm_content=" + utm_content;

// log final Outbound button link to console
console.log(outboundLink.href);
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to loop through the links (right now I'm looping through ALL anchors, but you will want to change that for your website).

Also by adding `|| ""` after the get basically that is saying "if exists in query string use it otherwise use empty"

```js
// create urlParams variable (constant) from URLSearchParams class using current window
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);


// set UTM medium, source and campaign variables (constants) based on results of URSearchParams
const utm_medium = urlParams.get('utm_medium') || ""
const utm_source = urlParams.get('utm_source') || ""
const utm_campaign = urlParams.get('utm_campaign') || ""
const utm_term = urlParams.get('utm_term') || ""
const utm_content = urlParams.get('utm_content') || ""


// get the Outbound button element
links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

links.forEach(function(outboundLink) {
  // edit Outbound button element property by appending the URL parameters
  outboundLink.href += "?utm_medium=" + utm_medium + "&utm_source=" + utm_source + "&utm_campaign=" + utm_campaign + "&utm_term=" + utm_term + "&utm_content=" + utm_content;

  // log final Outbound button link to console
  console.log(outboundLink.href);
});
```

```html
<a href="#test">x</a>
<a href="#tesxt">a</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you embed your typeform on your page, there is a property `transferableUrlParameters` in [Typeform Embed SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typeform/embed) to pass query parameters from the parent window to the embedded typeform.

```js
var url = "https://picsoung.typeform.com/to/QXS2h1" // NOTE: Replace with your typeform URL

const embedElement = document.querySelector('.target-dom-node') // NOTE: `.target-dom-node` is the target DOM element from your website or web app

window.typeformEmbed.makeWidget(
  embedElement,
  url, 
  {
    hideHeaders: true,
    hideFooter: true,
    transferableUrlParameters: ['utm_source', 'username'], //pass automatically from parent window to embedded typeform
    onSubmit: function () {
      console.log('Typeform successfully submitted')
    }
  }
)
```

[Full Example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tf-embed-with-params)